# Como resolver la falla de segmentación?

Tags: array, c, excepciones

Estoy desarrollando un programa en C donde se inserta una palabra "x", y quiero que por cada letra que la componga, sume 10 espacios en el alfabeto, es decir, si tengo la letra "a", le sumamos 10, entonces ahora será "k"; ´pero si la letra sumándole 10 pasa de "z", entonces se reinicia el abecedario nuevamente.

***El problema es que a la hora de ejecutar, tengo el error "Segmentation fault"; tengo la sospecha de que es un problema con los operadores de asignación***

Les adjunto el codigo:

```
void MoveTen (char *str){ // str = "testcase"

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (str[i] + 10 <= 'z')
            str[i] += 10; 
        else 
            str[i] = str[i] + 10 - 26; //Aquí surge la falla de segmentación
    }
 printf("%s", str);
}
```

**¿Por qué sucede esto?**

*Se que existen otras maneras de hacerlo, pero me gustaría resolver mi duda. Gracias*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás probando tu función realizando algo como:

```
MoveTen("testcase");
```

El error que obtienes es porque estás tratando de cambiar espacios en memoria que están asignados de manera estática como un dato **constante**. Cuando escribes en tu código `"testcase"` tu compilador crea una variable anónima de la constante y la referencia en lo que resta del código, podrías comprobar esto imprimiendo la dirección de `"testcase"` en cualquier lugar de tu código y verás como siempre es la misma... Nunca se genera una nueva variable, no importa en cual scope estés trabajando.

Cómo esta variable anónima está definida como una constante no permite que se cambien los valores de la misma y eso es exactamente lo que tratas de hacer en tu función cuando pasas una referencia de la misma. El `segmentation fault` es porque estás tratando de acceder a memoria que no debería de cambiarse.

Mira como al reservar un espacio en memoria editable (crear y asignar una variable) y luego pasarla el problema deja de ocurrir:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void MoveTen (char *str){ // str = "testcase"

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (str[i] + 10 <= 'z'){
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
        else {
            str[i] = str[i] + 10 - 26; //Aquí surge la falla de segmentación
        }
    }
 printf("%s", str);
} 


int main()
{
    char miTest[] = "testcase";
    MoveTen(miTest);

    return 0;
}
```

Mira este otro código en el cual utilizo otra técnica (por favor evitar usar este código, es una mala práctica crear arreglos de longitud variable, gracias [braver](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/166122/braver)) con fines exclusivamente didácticos que simule el pasar la string por valor a la función (se crea una copia de la string para trabajar con ella):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void MoveTen (char *inputStr){ // str = "testcase"
    
    char str[strlen(inputStr)+1];
    strncpy(str, inputStr, strlen(inputStr)+1);
    
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (str[i] + 10 <= 'z'){
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
        else {
            str[i] = str[i] + 10 - 26; //Aquí surge la falla de segmentación
        }
    }
 printf("%s", str);
} 


int main()
{
    MoveTen("testcase");

    return 0;
}
```

En resumidas cuentas el problema es que estás pasando por referencia un valor a una función que no puede ser editado... Al pasarlo por referencia se intenta cambiar el valor de la fuente y obtienes un `segmentation fault` por acceso indebido de memoria.

Comment: *Otra solución sería copiar la string a un buffer y trabajar con esta variable que si permite que la edites..* Esta linea está mal: `char str[sizeof(inputStr)];`.. puesto `inputStr` es un puntero, por lo que `sizeof` devolverá el tamaño del puntero.

Comment: Uy tienes razón MrDave! Es `strlen( )` Muchas gracias por la corrección.

Comment: Deberías evitar crear VLAs (arreglos de longitud variable) cuando sea posible. Por ejemplo, en `char str[strlen(inputStr)+1];` se puede desbordar la pila si la longitud de inputStr es muy grande.

Comment: Entiendo estas cosas, ya me ha pasado en posts pasados. Creo que mi descuido es no poner algún tipo de advertencia en la solución que doy o no especificar esto, mi objetivo con ese pedazo de código es meramente didáctico para que la persona entienda lo que está ocurriendo y entienda porque existe el error.